# Cause conflict syntax, at "git pull"

Tags: git

Let's suppose my co-worker changed a file and pushed on a remote repository.
Then, when I do `git pull` from remote,  I don't want to change my local file somehow "silently", I need to see differences, as usual conflict syntax.

Question is:  Can we force git, to cause conflict, when doing `git pull`?

Comment: Not exactly answering your direct question but... did you give a try to `git pull --rebase=interactive`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `git pull` is `git fetch` followed by one of `git merge` (default) or `git rebase`.

So you can check the differences at least by doing

```
git fetch
git diff @{u}
```

I also like `git show-branch`, so you can do

```
git show-branch @ @{u}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems there is no way to see difference exactly in conflict "style"? I mean something like: `<<<<<<< HEAD
old content
=======
new content
>>>>>>>  `

Comment: You would have to do a merge and have an actual conflict to see things like that—but you can also always check the result (git pull, git show) to see what changed during eg conflict resolution. This is more of a pre-check. @OTAR